# Update SQL Server Database On Table Edit/Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql-server, database, pdo

I have a dynamic HTML table that can be edited in multiple ways. There is an edit button where you can edit inline, the information of the rows and then click save to save the information. A deactivate button that grays out the row and an activate button that appears afterwards in order to reactivate it. And also and add row button that brings up a dialog box where you can hit add row again and add another row to the table.

However, while that is all nice...I want to write these changes/updates to a SQL Server database now so it actually saves them. I want to be able to automatically save these changes after each action (save, deactivate/activate, and add row) happens. I have never done this before so any help/advice/code would be appreciated!

JavaScript code:

```
// ----- Deactivate/Activate Row -----

$(document).on("click", "#html_master .deactivate", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $tr = $this.closest('tr');
  var action = $tr.hasClass('deactivated') ? 'activate' : 'deactivate';

  // ------ Confirmation box in order to deactivate/activate row -----
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to ' + action + ' this entry?')) {
    $tr.toggleClass('deactivated');
    $this.val(function (i, t) {
      return t == 'Deactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Deactivate';
    });
  }
});

// ----- Edit Row -----

$(document).on("click", "#html_master .edit", function () {
  var $this = $(this);
  var tds = $this.closest('tr').find('td').not('.mr_id').filter(function () {
    return $(this).find('.edit').length === 0;
  });
  if ($this.val() === 'Edit') {
    $this.val('Save');
    tds.prop('contenteditable', true);
  } else {
    var isValid = true;
    var errors = '';
    $('#myDialogBox').empty();
    // changed from here.......
    var elements = tds;
    if (tds.find('input').length > 0) {
      elements = tds.find('input');
    }
    elements.each(function (index, element) {
      var type = $(this).attr('class');
      var value = (element.tagName == 'INPUT') ? $(this).val() : $(this).text();
      // changed from here....... to here
      // ----- Switch statement that provides validation -----
      switch (type) {
        case "buyer_id":
          if (!$.isNumeric(value)) {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Buyer ID\n";
          }
          break;
        case "poc_n":
          if (value == value.match(/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/)) {
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Name\n";
          }
          break;
        case "poc_e":
          if (value == value.match(/^[\w\-\.\+]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-z0-9]{2,4}$/)) {
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Email\n";
          }
          break;
        case "poc_p":
          if (value == value.match('^[0-9 ()+/-]{10,}$')) {
            break;
          }
          else {
            isValid = false;
            errors += "Please enter a valid Phone Number\n";
          }
          break;
      }
    })
    if (isValid) {
      $this.val('Edit');
      tds.prop('contenteditable', false);
    } else {
      alert(errors);
    }
  }
});

// ----- Dialog Box -----

$( function() {   

    var dialog, form,

      emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
      phoneRegex = /^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$/,
      mr_name = $( "#mr_name" ),
      buyer_id = $( "#buyer_id" ),
      poc_n = $( "#poc_n" ),
      poc_e = $( "#poc_e" ),
      poc_p = $( "#poc_p" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( mr_name ).add( buyer_id ).add( poc_n ).add( poc_e ).add( poc_p ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );
  console.log(allFields);

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }

    function addVendor() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

      valid = valid && checkRegexp( mr_name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Please enter a valid vendor name" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( buyer_id, /^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$/, "Please enter a valid Buyer ID" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_n, /^[a-zA-Z ]*$/, "Please enter a valid name" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_e, emailRegex, "Please enter a valid email" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( poc_p, phoneRegex, "Please enter a valid phone number" );

      if ( valid ) {
        var $tr = $( "#html_master tbody tr" ).eq(0).clone();
        $.each(allFields, function(){
          $tr.find('.' + $(this).attr('id')).html( $(this).val() );
        });
        $tr.find('.mr_id').html( $( "#html_master tbody tr" ).length + 1 );
        $( "#html_master tbody" ).append($tr);

        /*
        $( "#html_master tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + mr_name.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + buyer_id.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + poc_n.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + poc_e.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + poc_p.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" );
        */
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
      }
      return valid;
    }

    var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Add Row": addVendor,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addVendor();
    });

    $( ".create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog( "open" );
    });
  } );
```

HTML/PHP code:

```
<?php
$host="xxxxxxxxx"; 
$dbName="xxxxx"; 
$dbUser="xxxxxxxxxxx"; 
$dbPass="xxxxxx";

$dbh = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=".$host."; Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Stage_Rebate_Master ORDER BY MR_ID ASC";
?>

<html>

<body> 

<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Vendor">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>

  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="mr_name">Vendor</label>
      <input type="text" name="mr_name" id="mr_name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="buyer_id">Buyer ID</label>
      <input type="text" name="buyer_id" id="buyer_id" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_n">POC Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_n" id="poc_n" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_e" id="poc_e" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <label for="poc_p">POC Phone</label>
      <input type="text" name="poc_p" id="poc_p" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">

      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: study some tutorials on AJAX. Other than that this question is far too broad. Also need to learn how to show a [mcve]. There seems to be a lot of code not relevant to what you are asking in the question

Comment: I updated my code. I took out a chunk of my HTML/PHP code, but I think that most of the JavaScript is necessary so everyone knows exactly what I am doing. And my question is simply, how can I automatically write the changes I make in the HTML table, to the database?

Comment: use ui events to trigger ajax requests. There are lots and lots of learning resources on web regarding ajax. Try getting something started and when you run into more specific problems you can get lots of help here

Comment: so how would that look then then using ui events to trigger ajax requests?

Comment: depends what behavior you want...and thus which event in the UI would trigger the request

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "what behavior you want?" so I can give you an accurate description?

Comment: Like when modal close is initiated, or an <input> in a row is blured etc. The event part should be relatively easy ... you need to get an understanding of the ajax part

Comment: I want an insert query to run when I click add row in the dialog box....i want an update query to run when I edit a row and then hit save...i am still not sure what I would want my query to look like whenever I deactivate/activate the row.

Comment: welll the ajax only communicates with server...the server script needs to do whatever is needed with the data sent and respond back to the ajax request accordingly

Comment: So if I am understanding this correctly...am I trying to hold all of the added information inside of an ajax request then use that to write a sql query?

Comment: Do the ajax tutorials. Can find lots of them that relate to form submissions. Then you will understand process better

Comment: Hmm alright, I'll try.

Comment: So I tried to look up some stuff and do it on my own...I followed the example from here...https://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/ but I still cannot figure this thing out.

Comment: so now you understand the concept better it now boils down to what you need to send ... if it's the form shown you can do something as simple as `$.post('someFile.php', $('#formId').serialize(), function(response){ /* do something with server response */})`

Comment: and that could be wrapped in a submit event handler for the form

Comment: Yes, it is the form shown that I will need posed...how would that look in my code then? and would that be in my JS file or my ajaxsubmit.php file?

Comment: I suggest you build a very simple html page with a form in it and play with that first. Get used to the various processes...then integrate into your app

Comment: Wondering if you're still around...i am completely stuck on this stuff

Answer (score -3):

Without Ajax - This can be done with a (PHP/ASP) 'pass-through' window.open - this is a window that you open which processes the passed parameters and writes them to an SQL database and then closes itself. This leaves the original site intact but updates the database with your changes.

So, window.open(saveChanges.php?param1=..&param2=..&etc,....)

The saveChanges.php file should read in the passed params and run the appropriate SQL to save updates.

Once completed, the saveChanges.php file should close itself with window.close()

Your database should now reflect the contents of your web page entries.

Comment: FAO:  Whoever gave this -1...  I don't understand - this works for me on either localhost or remote site -- why is this not an acceptable answer?  -- Thanks, I'd be interested to know...